# Prevent VS Code from overwriting my clipboard when clicking a link in the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code has a neat feature where if you search for something in the terminal `grep`/`ack` or similar tools, the resultant file links are clickable (with ctrl+click). I love that feature! Recently however I reinstalled VS Code with fresh settings, and a strange new default behavior has started that was definitely not present in my old install. Whenever I click links like that, in addition to opening the link, the name of the file is also copied into my clipboard, overwriting what I searched for.

My old work flow was copy search term, go to console, `grep <paste>`, click link, ctrl+f, . That doesn't work anymore, and I would prefer to restore the old mechanism, but due to the somewhat peculiar circumstances I'm not sure what I would search for to configure this behavior.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have `terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection` enabled maybe?

Comment: I do, and I want to keep it that way (and had it that way in the installation where it didn't overwrite my clipboard). Selecting text is not part of my problem, it happens when i just ctrl+double click a file name, without selecting anything